# assigning a string to a string variable throwing Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow,

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, datareader

While processing the following code am getting some error.

```
queryCommand= "select user_name,user_lastname,user_address from usertable"
objODBCDataReader = dbconObject.GetDataReader(queryCommand)
If objODBCDataReader.HasRows = True Then
   Dim userName = objODBCDataReader.Item("user_name").ToString() 'here it throws error as Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow
End If
```

`GetDataReader` is a method that that will accept the query as string and return the result as `Datareader`.

let me know why this error is occurring while assigning a string value to a string variable?

am using

```
VisualStudio 2012
mysql 5.0
odbc driver 3.51
64 bit os
```

Comment: sorry that was my mistake while copying the code. now i correct the code just see

Comment: what MySql & MySql connector version that you use?

Comment: How did you declare `lsfinyear`?

Comment: If you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) it might point out some problems in your code which are leading to it failing.

Comment: If you found your solution, please create and accept an answer containing it so that people with a similar problem in the future may find help as well :)

Comment: @SarathiV What happens if you use `userName = objODBCDataReader.Item(0).ToString()`, so that the *name* of the column is not involved?

Answer (score 0):

In your IF statement you are TESTING to see if ROWS exist,

At this point you have not READ any data?

```
queryCommand= "select user_name,user_lastname,user_address from usertable"
objODBCDataReader = dbconObject.GetDataReader(queryCommand)
If objODBCDataReader.HasRows = True Then
  objODBCDataReader.Read()
  lsfinyear = objODBCDataReader.Item("user_name") 'here it throws error as Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow
End If
```

Comment: it is not the answer, it will not solve my problem. please see my updates. i think the problem is with the `ODBC driver`

Answer (score 0):

I have few suggestions for you:

**1** Make us eof `using command` which will automatically dispose the connection at the end of using, you need not to bother about the connection issues even in case of any exception.

**2** Use `.Read` method to read a row, and then only you can access values from the corresponding columns using its column index or by the column name.

**3** You can use `while` instead for checking `hasRow` and then read.

Now consider the following code:

```
Dim queryString As String = "select user_name,user_lastname,user_address from usertable"
Using connection As New OdbcConnection(connectionString)
    Dim command As New OdbcCommand(queryString, connection)
    connection.Open()
    Dim reader As OdbcDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine("user name={0}", reader(0).ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("user lastname{0}", reader("user_lastname").ToString)
    End While      
    reader.Close()
End Using
```

You will get more more details and examples from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)